# Try To Get Voice From Mic

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, speech-recognition, python-multithreading

I work in a call center. I listen to the calls and rate them. The most common reason for the employees to lose points is staying silent for too long. I'm trying to write an application for this. The logic of the application is as follows:

My code is working but it doesn't reset the timer when it hears a sound. It needs to listen in a continuous loop and reset the timer when it hears a sound.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
import time
import threading
import tkinter as tk


def ses_alma():
    CHUNK = 1024
    FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
    CHANNELS = 1
    RATE = 44100
    sensitivity = 150  # Minimum algılanabilen ses şiddeti

    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

    stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

    print("Ses dinleme başladı...")

    last_sound_time = time.time()

    while True:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        audio_data = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)

        if np.max(np.abs(audio_data)) < sensitivity:
            if time.time() - last_sound_time >= 1:
                sessizlik_suresi.set(sessizlik_suresi.get() + 1)
        else:
            last_sound_time = time.time()
            sessizlik_suresi.set(0)

        if np.max(np.abs(audio_data)) > 100:  # Ses şiddeti 100'ün üzerinde ise süreyi sıfırla
            sessizlik_suresi.set(0)

        time.sleep(1)

    stream.stop_stream()
    stream.close()
    p.terminate()


def uyarı_ver():
    while True:
        if sessizlik_suresi.get() >= 25:  # 25 saniye sessizlik tespit edilirse
            show_popup()
            sessizlik_suresi.set(0)
        time.sleep(1)

def show_popup():
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.geometry("200x100")
    popup.title("UYARI")
    message = tk.Label(popup, text="25 saniyeden fazla sessizlik!")
    message.pack()
    popup.after(5000, popup.destroy) # 5 saniye sonra uyarı penceresini kapatır

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x100")
    root.title("Sessizlik Uyarısı")
    root.configure(bg="black")

    sessizlik_suresi = tk.IntVar()
    sessizlik_suresi.set(0)

    time_label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=sessizlik_suresi, font=("Arial Bold", 36), bg="black", fg="white")
    time_label.pack()

    ses_alma_thread = threading.Thread(target=ses_alma)
    uyarı_thread = threading.Thread(target=uyarı_ver)

    ses_alma_thread.start()
    uyarı_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()

    ses_alma_thread.join()
    uyarı_thread.join()
```

1- It will constantly listen to the sound from the microphone
2- It will give a pop-up warning to the representative if they stay silent for too long.
3- It should give a warning when the time reaches 30 seconds.

My code is working but it doesn't reset the timer when it hears a sound. It needs to listen in a continuous loop and reset the timer when it hears a sound. How can I add this functionality to my code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to change this:

```
if np.max(np.abs(audio_data)) > 100:  # Ses şiddeti 100'ün üzerinde ise süreyi sıfırla
        sessizlik_suresi.set(0)
```

To this:

```
if np.max(np.abs(audio_data)) > 100:  # Ses şiddeti 100'ün üzerinde ise süreyi sıfırla
        last_sound_time = time.time()
        sessizlik_suresi.set(0)
```

Assuming your if condition is correct, this will reset the last sound time when the detected volume goes above 100. I translated your comment and it seems this is what it's meant to do.